How can declare return type as literal object from literal array argument?
interface inter<A extends string, B extends string> {
    a: A
    b: B
}

function ato<A extends string, B extends string>(...p: Array<inter<A, B>>): {[K in A]: B} {
    return {} as {[K in A]: B}
}

const result = ato({
    a: 'a0',
    b: 'b0'
}, {
    a: 'a1',
    b: 'b1'
}
)

Type of result is
{
    a0: "b0" | "b1"
    a1: "b0" | "b1"
}

I want to change the return type to:
{
 a0: 'b0'
 a1: 'b1'
}

Do you get it what I want?
Something like {[K in A]: V in B} but this syntax is invalid.
Is it possible in TypeScript?

I'd suggest you write ato like this:
function ato<const T extends Inter<string, string>>(
    ...p: Array<T>
) {
    return {} as { [U in T as U["a"]]: U["b"] }
}

Instead of making the function generic in the union in two different type parameters A and B that separate the a and b properties from each other (and therefore cannot keep track of the correlations), we've made it generic in T, the union of types of elements of p.  That is, instead of A being "a0" | "a1" and B being "b0" | "b1", we now have T being {a: "a0", b: "b0"} | {a: "a1", b: "b1"}, which has enough information to use.
Note that T is a const type parameter because we want TypeScript to infer literal types for the a and b properties. Otherwise we'd get T being {a: string, b: string} which isn't useful.
Finally, for the output type, we can use key remapping on the union T to pull out the a property as a key and the b property as a value.

Let's test it:
const result = ato({
    a: 'a0',
    b: 'b0'
}, {
    a: 'a1',
    b: 'b1'
})

/* const result: {
    a0: "b0";
    a1: "b1";
} */

Looks good.
Playground link to code

Amazing! Thank you very much

You can define the following types:
type Inter<A extends string, B extends string> = {
    a: A
    b: B
};

type Keys<T> = keyof T;
type Val<T, P extends keyof T> = T[P];
type ToTuple<T> = T extends Inter<infer A, infer B> ? [A, B] : never;

type ToObject<T extends [string, string]> = {
    [key in T[0]]: Extract<T, [key, any]>[1]
};

type MapInter<T> = T extends Inter<infer A, infer B> ?
    ToObject<ToTuple<Inter<A, B>>> : never;

type UnionToIntersection<U> = 
    (U extends any ? 
      (k: U) => void : never) extends 
      (k: infer I extends U) => void ? 
    I : never;

function map<
  T,
  R = T extends Inter<infer A, infer B> ? MapInter<Inter<A, B>> : never
>(iter: T[]): UnionToIntersection<R> {
    return {} as any
}

It works like this:
const result = map(
  [
    {
      a: 'a0' as const,
      b: 'b0' as const
    },
    {
        a: 'a1' as const,
        b: 'b1' as const
    }
  ]
);

type x1 = typeof result.a0; // "b0"
type x2 = typeof result.a1; // "b1"
type x3 = typeof result.a; // ERROR
type x4 = typeof result.b; // ERROR
type x5 = typeof result.b0; // ERROR
type x6 = typeof result.b1; // ERROR

Here is a demo.

Why the extra ToTuple step? Just use T extends Inter…, then T['a'] and T['b'].
